# Как получить SID Windows-пользователя?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Мне нужно узнать SID текущего пользователя для доступа к папке. Написал следующий код:

```
import os
import win32security

desc = win32security.GetFileSecurity(
    ".", win32security.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION
)
sid = desc.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()

sidstr = win32security.ConvertSidToStringSid(sid)
print("Sid is", sidstr)
```

Вывододит SID в следующем формате:

```
[Sid is S-x-x-xx-xxx]
```

А нужно в таком:

```
[S-x-x-xx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx]
```

Программа будет запускаться наа стороннем ПК, поэтому не будет возможностим получить SID через командную строку. Как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Я у себя попробовал в Jupyter Notebook от Anaconda - выдаёт именно в длинном формате, как вы хотели.

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32security
import os

user_info = win32security.LookupAccountName(None,os.getlogin())
sid = win32security.ConvertSidToStringSid(user_info[0])

print(sid)
```

Выходной формат:

```
S-x-x-xx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx
```